# Determine which of the formulas hold for all invertible nxn matrices A and B

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

1: $(A+B)(A-B) = A^2-B^2$

2: $ABA^{-1} = B$

3: A+I2 is invertible

4: $(ABA^-1)^5=AB^5A^{-1}$

5: $(AB)^{-1}= A^{-1}B^{-1}$

6: $A^6B^6$ is invertible

I have no idea!!!! Which hold and why? Any help would be great guys!

Answer (score 1):

Couple of hints:

1) Try expanding the product. Note that for matrices $AB\neq BA$ in general.

2) Try multiplying with $A$ on both sides.

3) What if $A=-I2$?

4) $(AB)^n=B^nA^n$

5) See hint above.

6) $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$. A matrix is invertible if its determinant is not zero.

Comment: $(AB)^n=B^nA^n$ is false for $n=1$ and matrices $A$ and $B$ which don't commute.

Answer (score 0):

- The 6 is true, by writing $(A^6B^6)^{-1}=(B^{-1})^6(A^{-1})^6.$
- The 4 is true by writing $(ABA^{-1})^5=AB\underset{=I_n}{\underbrace{A^{-1}A}}BA^{-1}ABA^{-1}ABA^{-1}ABA^{-1}=AB^5A^{-1}$
- For the 1-2-5, you can 
  see that they hold if $AB=BA$ but find a counter-example with $AB\neq BA$.
- For the $3$, $A=\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$ is invertible $(A^2=I_2)$ but $A+I_2=0$ is not invertible.

Comment: Thanks guys really helpful!

Comment: @Phil You're welcome.